# Finding the DFT size in relation to an OFDM encoded signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing, digital-communications, fourier

I am completely lost here. How do I go about determining the size of the DFT matrix used in conjunction with an OFDM encoded signal? I have researched this a lot but cannot find a solid answer? Is it determined by the number of subcarriers, frequency of the signal or other characteristics?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of the subcarriers,i.e the size of the DFT is the same number of the subcarriers of the OFDM